# How to register user using Authentication in Firebase and add user to "user" collection in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a working "register" and "login" authentication process in my iOS app. I'm now trying to add every user that registers inside a "users" collection in my Firebase Database.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func bottoneRegistrati(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    // Verifico nome e cognome
    
    let erroreNome_Cognome = validazioneCampi()
    
    if erroreNome_Cognome != nil {

        mostraErrore(erroreNome_Cognome!)
    } else if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {   
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
                if let e = error { 
                    self.labelErrore.text = e.localizedDescription
                } else {
                    
                    let nome = self.nomeTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let cognome = self.cognomeTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    

                    let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    
                    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
                    let userData = [
                        "nome": nome,
                        "cognome": cognome,
                        "email": user?.email ?? "",
                        "uid": user?.uid ?? ""
                    ]
                    db.collection("utenti").document(user!.uid).setData(userData) { err in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                        } else {
                            print("Document added successfully!")
                        }
                    }
                    

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registratiAWelcome", sender:self)
                }
            }
        }
    


}
```

So, everything actually works, apart from the following lines of code that should add the user to my database collection called "utenti", which is "users" in my language...

Code:

```
                let db = Firestore.firestore()

                let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
                let userData = [
                    "nome": nome,
                    "cognome": cognome,
                    "email": user?.email ?? "",
                    "uid": user?.uid ?? ""
                ]
                db.collection("utenti").document(user!.uid).setData(userData) { err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        print("Document added successfully!")
                    }
                }
```

And this is my Firebase Database:

[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry if I answer only now, but I was sick and at the hospital... Anyways, the reason why I'm asking the question here is because I can't seem to get an error...

Comment: So what output do you get from your code?

Comment: I get nothing, the code executes perfectly, the registration appears on Firebase and it automatically authenticates the user. It just does not register in the database.

Comment: So you get "documented added successfully"? Or "Error adding document"?  If neither then it seems likely the code wasn't called. Have you set breakpoints and stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors or maybe the code really isn't executing for some reason. I'll try again with the debugger. Any other tips?

Anyways thanks for the help, you've been very kind!

Comment: @Paulw11 after messing around some more I got an error!

Error adding document: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It was a permission problem in my Firebase Database rules.

Thanks to Paulw11 for helping me out!

Here are the rules I changed:

[image: Rules]

What I changed was "false" to "true" at line 5.

Note: use this only for testing, not for deployment!